# How to run a macro in different excel worksheets? It is not looping

Tags: excel, vba

There is data in 8 columns in worksheet 1. Similar information is in worksheet 2. I am trying to run the macro in both worksheets. (one after the other)

I am trying to exit the macro in worksheet 1 once a blank cell is found in column A. Then move to the next worksheet. Once macro is completed in worksheet 2 then exit sub.

I am not a programmer at all. I am just learning a few things.

Please let me know how to do this.

```
 '''
    Sub Macro3()

      Dim cell As Range
      Dim i As Integer, row As Integer, column As Integer
      Dim ws As Worksheet
      i = 0
      row = 1
      column = 1
          For Each ws In Worksheets
             For Each cell In Range("$A:$A")
                If Cells(row, 1) = "" Then
                   Exit Sub
                Else
                   If Mid(Cells(row, column), 1, 1) = "R" Then
                   Cells(row, column + 1) = "RES" & "_" & Cells(row, column + 5)
                   ElseIf Mid(Cells(row, column), 1, 2) = "FI" Then
                   Cells(row, column + 1) = "FID" & "_" & Cells(row, column + 5)
                   ElseIf Mid(Cells(row, column), 1, 1) = "F" Then
                   Cells(row, column + 1) = "FUSE" & "_" & Cells(row, column + 5)
                   ElseIf Mid(Cells(row, column), 1, 1) = "C" Then
                 Else
                   Cells(row, column + 1) = "N/A"
                   Cells(row, column + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
               End If
                  i = i + 1
                  row = i + 1
               End If
           Next cell
         Next
       End Sub
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out. Thanks for your feedback. This is the updated code:

```
 '''
 Sub MacroTest()
 For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Activate
        i = 0
        row = 1
        column = 1
            For Each cell In Range("$A:$A")
                If Cells(row, 1) = "" Then
            Exit For
                Else
                    If Mid(Cells(row, column), 1, 1) = "R" Then
                      Cells(row, column + 1) = "RES" & "_" & Cells(row, column + 5)
                      ElseIf Mid(Cells(row, column), 1, 2) = "FI" Then
                      Cells(row, column + 1) = "FID" & "_" & Cells(row, column + 5)
                      ElseIf Mid(Cells(row, column), 1, 1) = "F" Then
                      Cells(row, column + 1) = "FUSE" & "_" & Cells(row, column + 5)
                    Else
                         Cells(row, column + 1) = "N/A"
                         Cells(row, column + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                    End If
                        i = i + 1
                        row = i + 1
                  End If
            Next cell
        Next ws
     End If
   End If
 End Sub
 '''
```

Answer (score 0):

Different possible solutions but at the moment you are telling it to exit sub on the first blank cell not go onto the next worksheet. Maybe trying adding the count of worksheets and then exit if the you are on the final worksheet (assuming you just have 2 sheets).

If the blankcell means there is no more data in the worksheet then you would be better to just add a variable to find the last used row and change `row = row +1` to a `For row =1 to lastrow` at the start of your loop with an extra `Next` at the bottom, where `lastrow=Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` Then the cell check can just end at the last used row and move onto the next worksheet.

```
  Dim i As Integer, column As Integer, wscount as Integer
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim row as Long ' you should use long rather than integer as if you ever have data beyond row 32kish the code will fail as that as integers stop there
  Dim MyAr(3)
  Dim NewAR(3)
  wscount = Application.Sheets.Count
  MyAr(1) = "R"
  MyAr(2) = "FI"
  MyAr(3) = "F"
  NewAr(1) = "RES"
  NewAr(2) = "FID"
  NewAr(3) = "FUSE"
  column = 1
      For Each ws In Worksheets
      lastrow=Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         For row =1 to lastrow
            If Cells(row, 1) = "" and ActiveSheet.Index = wscount Then
               Exit Sub*
          
          For i =1 to 3
          If Mid(Cells(row, column), 1, 1) = MyAr(i) Then _
               Cells(row, column + 1) = NewAr(i) & "_" & Cells(row, column + 5) 'If you are just looking at the start of a cell you can use Left as well as Mid
          Next i
               
     If Mid(Cells(row, column), 1, 1) = "C" Then _
         Cells(row, column + 1) = "N/A"
         Cells(row, column + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
     End If
                           

     Next row
     Next ws
   End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: There are no repeated `Else` keywords within an `If` .. `End If` structure, reorganize the logic or try `ElseIf` :-) btw always use fully qualified range references.

Comment: Did you ever try your own answer? a) `If` .. `Else` .. `Else` .. `Endif` is no correct syntax; b) looping through the worksheets collection without fully qualified range references doesn't influence the returned cell values as VBA then always assumes the active sheet.